# How to make the checkbox filled with already given data in laravel

Tags: laravel

For example if I submitted the book details including genders boy, girl, man and woman and I submitted only boy checkbox while submitting the book details. If I want to edit that book including the gender details in the edit page it should check the boy checkbox.
I need some help guys...
Thanks

Comment: you have to put your code in your question. show us what have you tried.

Comment: fix your formatting and dip into https://medium.com/@renatoperes01/how-to-handle-enums-in-laravel-without-external-packages-1794f3f3294e

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="checkbox" {{ $isChecked ? 'checked="checked"' : '' }} />
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe this can help you :

```
<input type="checkbox" @if($book->gender == 1 /*or $book->gender == 'boy'*/) checked @endif name="gender">
```

if You use numeric for gender maybe, You're gender columns should be 0 or 1 or 2 or 3